# Прокрутка RecyclerView до самого низа

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Как при добавлении нового элемента в `RecyclerView` осуществить прокрутку списка? Так чтобы отображался последний, добавленный элемент?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для этого у `RecyclerView` есть метод `smoothScrollToPosition(int position)`, принимающий номер элемента к коему надо его спроскроллить. Засим, в вашем случае, надо туда передать `размер отображаемого списка - 1`:

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);
```

Comment: То, что надо! Спасибо!