# Скролл при добавлении элемента в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Есть RecyclerView, в который могут добавляться элементы в начало и конец списка.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recylerview_message_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/main_appBarLayout">
```

При добавлении в начало все ок, но при добавлении в конец все автоматически скроллится на 4 элемента вверх.

Инициализация recyclerView:

```
    @Override
    public void showMessages(List<MessageModel> messages) {
        chatMessages = messages;
        Collections.sort(chatMessages);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(messageListAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager, this));

        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        chatLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        layoutChatBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Добавление нового элемента (Закомментированно то что я уже попробовал)

```
@Override
public void addMessage(MessageModel message) {
    //List<MessageModel> oldMessages = new ArrayList<>(chatMessages);

    chatMessages.add(message);

    //linearLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);

    //recyclerView.setAdapter(messageListAdapter);

    //messageListAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, chatMessages.size());
    //messageListAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(messageListAdapter.getItemCount(), chatMessages.size());
    //messageListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //messageListAdapter.notifyItemInserted(chatMessages.size());

    //DiffUtil.DiffResult result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new CustomDiffUtilCallback(old, chatMessages));
    //result.dispatchUpdatesTo(messageListAdapter);
}
```

Как отключить автоматический скролл при добавлении элементов в конец списка? При добавлении в начало все работает с `messageListAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);`

Comment: попробуйте сохранить текущую позицию, после добавления нового элемента - поставить скрол на прежднюю позицию - ну это как костыльный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

возможно [это ответ на ваш](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487943/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-recyclerview-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0)

Используйте recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);
```

Comment: Мне не нужно в самый низ, мне нужно чтобы скролла не было